# How do I display an image from an API in a Django

Tags: python, html, django, api

I am creating a website in Django. On the homepage I would like to display a different image on the every time the site's reloaded. I found an API with all the pictures I think I would ever need but I've never used an API before and I've found researching how to do this simple specific thing overwhelming. The docs didn't help me much either.

I'm trying to use https://waifu.pics/docs. When you give a specific URL (ex. https://api.waifu.pics/sfw/dance ) you get a JSON with the actual Image URL you'd need to use. My first attempt:

```
<a href="{% url 'index'%}"><img src="https://api.waifu.pics/sfw/dance" alt="Homepage IMG"> </a>
```

I knew it would be more complicated than this but my first idea was to use the link in an ... that didn't work, because I need to get the specific URL every time. Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: You can't by only putting a URL, you need first make an HTTP request, then use the response to build the img tag.